# How to get hosted fields value in braintree

Tags: braintree

Is it possible to get the hosted field value in blur event?
In my payment page, if customer enter a special card number like '1122' then it should be used with braintree sandbox enveirment, but if use real credit card number it should be used production enveirment. This is my requirement. I want to know is it possible to implement it?
My soulation is like this, in blur event for the number field, check the value, if test call sandbox, otherwise call production. I don't know if it is possible.

Thanks

```
braintree.hostedFields.create({
        client: client,
        styles: {
            input: {
                'font-size': '14px',
                'font-family': 'monospace'
            }
        },
        fields: {
            number: {
                selector: '#number',
                placeholder: '4000 0000 0000 1091',
                prefill: '4111111111111111'
            },
            cvv: {
                selector: '#cvv',
                placeholder: '123',
                prefill: '123'
            },
            expirationDate: {
                selector: '#date',
                placeholder: '01 / 2020',
                prefill: '02/2020'
            }
        }
    }, function (err, hostedFieldsInstance) {
        components['hostedFields'] = hostedFieldsInstance;
        if (components.threeDSecure && components.hostedFields) {
            setupForm();
        }
        hostedFieldsInstance.on('blur', function(event) {
            var field = event.fields[event.emittedBy];
            $(field.container).addClass('is-valid');
            console.log(event);
            //if it is special card number, call again to use different environment

        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Full disclosure, I work at Braintree. If you have further questions, please [contact Support](https://help.braintreepayments.com).</sub>

The nature of Hosted Fields is to prevent you from needing to interact with the credit card number itself. The closest you can get to finding details about the credit card is in the [`tokenizePayload`](https://braintree.github.io/braintree-web/current/HostedFields.html#~tokenizePayload) returned from a successful tokenization call. Even with that, the payload does not specify whether the card is a test card.

In the sandbox environment, [a validation error](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/general/validation-errors/all/java#code-81717) will be thrown if you attempt to use a non-sandbox card in your API requests:

> 81717 - Credit card number is not an accepted test number.

In the production environment, using a test card will result in a [processor decline](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/general/processor-responses/authorization-responses#declines).

All that said, I'd recommend not trying to mix production and sandbox environments conditionally. It is best to not mix these environments, as there are many instances to account for and it'd be best to not accidentally send incorrect data to the incorrect environment.

Comment: I get why you can't get the value of a cc number, but how about cardholderName or zipCode?

Comment: Nevermind, found out you can use the `payload.details` that comes back from calling `hostedFieldsInstance?.tokenize` to get all the input values except for card number.

Comment: Actually, zipCode is not included for some reason.